# Regular Expression For EURO Format

Tags: regex, expression, euro

I want the EURO format to be accepted only in the following forms.

Three digits with "**.**" Be segregated.

i found this expression but not work in my way:

```
^(0|(([1-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}){1}(\ [0-9]{3}){0,})),(([0-9]{2})|\-\-)([\ ]{1})(€|EUR|EURO){1}$
```

I want it to be exactly like the following:

1.123,45

1,23

1.234.567,45

0,56

I want two digit cent to be mandatory.

**thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
^(?!0\d)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `(?!0\d)` negative lookahead, make sure there's no leading `0`s like `01,25`, remove it if it is allowed
- `\d{1,3}` 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})*` followed by any occurances of texts like `.123`
- `,\d{2}` followed by 2 decimal digits, mandatory. If you want it to be optional, replace it with `(?:,\d{2})?`
- `$` end of the string

See the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/rp6uk7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
-?(\d{1,3})(\.\d{3})*(,\d{2})? (€|EURO?)
```

This will capture the numbers. You never ever need `{1}` because that is the default assumption. Also spaces don't need to be escaped.